# how to combine first and last name in an EntityType form symfony 7

Tags: symfony

I have an entity Account with two fields first_name and last_name, i've build a form with component of symfony. I would like to be able to retrieve the first and last name and concatenate them into the choice_label.

```
         ->add('user', EntityType::class, [
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'form-select'
                ],
                'label' => "user",
                'label_attr' => [
                    'class' => 'form-label  mt-4'
                ],
                'class' => Account::class,
                'choice_label' => 'first_name last_name', // HERE
            ])
```

I tried to create a method in my Account Entity but I can't call it

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also create a getFullName() method in your Account Entity

```
public function getFullName(){
return $this->firstName.' '.$this->lastName;
}
```

And then in your form you can use the choice_label option like this:

```
->add('user', EntityType::class, [
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'form-select'
                ],
                'label' => "user",
                'label_attr' => [
                    'class' => 'form-label  mt-4'
                ],
                'class' => Account::class,
                'choice_label' => 'fullName', // HERE
            ])
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working, thank you everybody for your differents methods. I understund better.

Answer (score 1):

see https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#choice-label

```
     ->add('user', EntityType::class, [
            'attr' => [
                'class' => 'form-select'
            ],
            'label' => "user",
            'label_attr' => [
                'class' => 'form-label  mt-4'
            ],
            'class' => Account::class,
            'choice_label' => function (EntityClass $entity): string {
                  return sprintf("%s %s", $entity->getFirstName(), $entity->getLastName());
            },
        ])
```

Answer (score 1):

pass a callback function for more control.

```
 $builder->add('user', EntityType::class, [
    'class' => Account::class,
    'choice_label' => function (Account $account): string {
     return $account->getFullName();
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a private function like this :

```
private function getFullName(){
   return $this->firstName.' '.$this->lastName;
}
```

and call it inside :

```
->add('user', EntityType::class, [
      'attr' => [
      'class' => 'form-select'],
      'label' => "user",
      'label_attr' => [
          'class' => 'form-label  mt-4'
      ],
        'class' => Account::class,
                'choice_label' => $this->getFullName(), // HERE
            ])
```